# How to bind rows of data.frames in a list and add a new column which contains the names of list elements?

Tags: r

I have two data.frames in a list, the first one has name "one", and the second one name "two"

```
data (mtcars)

xx <- list (one = mtcars [1:5, ],
            two = mtcars  [6:10, ])
```

I would like to bind the rows, simultaneously creating a new column, e.g. data.frame.name, it should contain values of "one" or "two" depending on if a particular row was from data.frame "one" or "two".

PS: naturally I need a solution for many data.frames, with different number of rows, the mtcars dataset is used as an example.

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(xx, .id = 'id')`